# git diff two branches and show only unmodified files

Tags: git

In a branch NewFeature I have a xml schema change and I like to check if all xml files in all unit tests had been modified correctly.

I like to find all unmodified files between two branches. Something like this

```
git aresame develop NewFeature -- **/*.xml
```

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960074/any-way-to-list-unmodified-files-in-git

Answer (score 1):

```
git ls-tree -r develop | grep '\sblob\s' | grep '.xml$' | awk '{print $3,$4}' > foo.txt
git ls-tree -r NewFeature | grep '\sblob\s' | grep '.xml$' | awk '{print $3,$4}' >> foo.txt
sort foo.txt | uniq -d | awk '{print $2}'
```

`git ls-tree -r` prints `<mode> SP <type> SP <object> TAB <file>` of all tracked files.

`grep '\sblob\s'` excludes `trees` and `submodules`, and `grep '.xml$'` includes xml files only.

`awk '{print $3,$4}'` ignores `mode` changes like from `0644` to `0755`. If you care about such changes, remove this part.

`sort foo.txt | uniq -d` prints the files whose paths and hashes are the same on both branches, and `awk '{print $2}'` prints the paths only.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to ElpieKay solution:
(one line, no mode check)

```
comm -3 <(git diff --name-only develop..NewFeature | grep '.xml$') <(git ls-tree -r --name-only develop | grep '.xml$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your great comments I combined several ideas into my final solution

```
comm -3 -1 <(git diff --name-only develop NewFeature -- **/*.xml|sort)  <(git ls-tree develop -r | grep -Ei '\sblob\s.+\.xml$' | cut -f 2 | sort)
```

**Explanation:**

- `git diff --name-only develop NewFeature -- **/*.xml|sort` lists all changed xml files in sorted order
- `git ls-tree develop -r | grep -Ei '\sblob\s.+\.xml$' | cut -f 2 | sort` prints all xml files in the original development branch
- `comm -3 -1 ...` Compares sorted files line by line and suppresses lines that are only in the NewFeature branch (-1), and files that are in both branches (-3)